# Gerar média entre datas

Tags: sql

Estou aprendendo SQL e ainda tenho muita coisa a aprender, mas estou tentando gerar um relatório e encontrei alguma dificuldades.
Fiz essa primeira consulta:

```
/* Aqui estou selecionando as colunas e gerando a média entre a data de entrada e saído da tramitação */
SELECT PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo AS "ID do Subassunto"
    , PPRO.pro_processo AS "Número do Processo"
    , PPRO.pro_ano AS "Ano"
    , PPF.prf_estagio AS "Estágio"
    , PPT.prt_nome AS "Subassunto"
    , PPFA.fas_nome AS "Atividade"
    , DATEDIFF(MINUTE,PPF.prf_data_chegada,PPF.prf_data_saida) AS "Tempo Gasto em Minutos"
/* Aqui estou selecionando as tabelas e seus relacionamentos */
    FROM prl_proposicoes AS PPRO
        INNER JOIN pro_proposicoes_fases AS PPF 
            ON  PPRO.cod_proposicao = PPF.cod_proposicao
        LEFT JOIN prl_proposicoes_situacoes AS PPS 
            ON PPRO.cod_proposicao_situacao = PPS.cod_proposicao_situacao
        INNER JOIN prl_proposicoes_tipos AS PPT 
            ON PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo = PPT.cod_proposicao_tipo
        INNER JOIN prl_proposicoes_tipos_grandes AS PPTG 
            ON PPT.cod_proposicao_tipo_grande = PPTG.cod_proposicao_tipo_grande            
        INNER JOIN prl_fases AS PPFA 
           ON PPF.cod_fase_entrada = PPFA.cod_fase
       INNER JOIN prl_setores 
           ON PPF.cod_setor_despacho = prl_setores.cod_setor
/* Aqui estou colocanco as condições da consulta */
    WHERE PPRO.pro_ano = '2020' 
        AND PPT.prt_area = 'ELE'
        AND PPRO.pro_processo = '353'
        AND PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo = '1844010'
/* Aqui estou ordenando as atividades */
    ORDER BY PPF.prf_estagio DESC
```

Que me retornou esse resultado:

[image: Tela 01]

Do resultado acima precisa gerar a média de tempo gasto por `"Atividade"`, então fiz a seguinte consulta:

```
WITH Consulta
AS (SELECT PPT.prt_area AS "Área", PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo AS "ID do Subassunto"
    , PPRO.pro_processo AS "Número do Processo", PPRO.pro_ano AS "Ano"
    , PPF.prf_estagio AS "Estágio", PPT.prt_nome AS "Subassunto"
    , PPFA.fas_nome AS "Atividade", DATEDIFF(MINUTE,PPF.prf_data_chegada,PPF.prf_data_saida) AS "Tempo"
    FROM prl_proposicoes AS PPRO
        INNER JOIN pro_proposicoes_fases AS PPF 
            ON  PPRO.cod_proposicao = PPF.cod_proposicao
        LEFT JOIN prl_proposicoes_situacoes AS PPS 
            ON PPRO.cod_proposicao_situacao = PPS.cod_proposicao_situacao
        INNER JOIN prl_proposicoes_tipos AS PPT 
            ON PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo = PPT.cod_proposicao_tipo
        INNER JOIN prl_proposicoes_tipos_grandes AS PPTG 
            ON PPT.cod_proposicao_tipo_grande = PPTG.cod_proposicao_tipo_grande            
        INNER JOIN prl_fases AS PPFA 
           ON PPF.cod_fase_entrada = PPFA.cod_fase
       INNER JOIN prl_setores 
           ON PPF.cod_setor_despacho = prl_setores.cod_setor
    WHERE PPRO.pro_ano = '2020' 
        AND PPT.prt_area = 'ELE'
        AND PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo = '1844010')
SELECT Consulta.Atividade, AVG(Consulta.Tempo)
FROM Consulta
WHERE Consulta.[ID do Subassunto] = '1844010'
    AND Consulta.Área = 'ELE'
    AND Consulta.Estágio = '2'
GROUP BY Consulta.Atividade
ORDER BY Consulta.Estágio
```

Porém está retornando erro, conforme print:

[image: Tela de Erro]

Comment: Qual o sentido desse `ORDER BY Consulta.Estágio` se você colocou `AND Consulta.Estágio = '2'` em sua cláusula WHERE?

Comment: O AND Consulta.Estágio = '2' pode desconsiderar, foi uma condição que estava testando, mas o ORDER BY Consulta.Estágio é para ordenar por Estágio/Fases do processo, mas pode ser retirado também. Mas o que quero é uma consulta onde eu pegue o Subassunto (Tipo de Processo) com suas respectivas Atividades, para extrair a média de tempo gasto de todos os processos achando qual é a atividade que está consumindo mais tempo

Comment: Observe que na consulta que gerei foi apenas para um processo específico (nº 353 de Licença sem Vencimento) mas a ideia é gerar de todos os processo de "Licença sem Vencimento" e achar a média da atividade que está consumindo mais tempo e da que está consumindo menos tempo.

Answer (score -2):

```
WITH Consulta
AS (SELECT PPT.prt_area AS "Área"
         , PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo AS "ID do Subassunto"
         , PPRO.pro_processo AS "Número do Processo"
         , PPRO.pro_ano AS "Ano"
         , PPF.prf_estagio AS "Estágio"
         , PPT.prt_nome AS "Subassunto"
         , PPFA.fas_nome AS "Atividade" 
         , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PPF.prf_data_chegada, PPF.prf_data_saida) AS "Tempo"
    FROM prl_proposicoes AS PPRO
    INNER JOIN pro_proposicoes_fases AS PPF 
        ON PPRO.cod_proposicao = PPF.cod_proposicao
    LEFT JOIN prl_proposicoes_situacoes AS PPS 
        ON PPRO.cod_proposicao_situacao = PPS.cod_proposicao_situacao
    INNER JOIN prl_proposicoes_tipos AS PPT 
        ON PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo = PPT.cod_proposicao_tipo
    INNER JOIN prl_proposicoes_tipos_grandes AS PPTG 
        ON PPT.cod_proposicao_tipo_grande = PPTG.cod_proposicao_tipo_grande            
    INNER JOIN prl_fases AS PPFA 
        ON PPF.cod_fase_entrada = PPFA.cod_fase
    INNER JOIN prl_setores 
        ON PPF.cod_setor_despacho = prl_setores.cod_setor
    WHERE PPRO.pro_ano = '2020' 
    --AND PPT.prt_area = 'ELE'
    --AND PPRO.cod_proposicao_tipo = '1844010'
)
SELECT Consulta.Atividade
--     , Consulta.Estágio
     , MIN(Consulta.Tempo) tempo_minimo
     , AVG(Consulta.Tempo) tempo_medio
     , MAX(Consulta.Tempo) tempo_maximo
FROM Consulta
WHERE Consulta.[ID do Subassunto] = '1844010'
AND Consulta.Área = 'ELE'
--AND Consulta.Estágio = '2'
GROUP BY Consulta.Atividade
--       , Consulta.Estágio
--ORDER BY Consulta.Estágio
```

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, mas teria como incluir a coluna do Subassunto junto?
Pois o Subassunto é o tipo de processo e cada Subassunto possui suas atividades específicas, se desse para entrar o Subassunto seria melhor para gerar o relatório.
O resultado ficaria mais ou menos assim:
SUBASSUNTO | ATIVIDADE  |  TEMPO MÍNIMO  | TEMPO MÉDIO  | TEMPO MÁXIMO
Licença               Protocolar          0                            1                           2
Licença               Analisar             3                             5                          9